# WCF Test Client error message: The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: wcf, testing, client

I must be missing something...

I have a simple service that will be hosted in a Web Service; however, at this point it's not. I'm using the Windows Service Host and WCF Test Client, which are both on my local development machine. The service starts and the WCF Test Client finds the service, and I provide the expected details, and nothing been changed on the config file for client.
However, when I click on Invoke button I get the following exception:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
>
> The caller was not authenticated by the service.

Comment: Also the Config File is generated by the WCF Test Client, which use <wsHttpBinding> on both <binding> and <client>.

Comment: perhaps, you can post `serviceModel` element from both server and client configuration!